# open a command prompt from java code and run some commands and read the cmd prompt display?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I need to open a command prompt from java code and run some commands on the same and after that I need to read that command prompt output in java code in real time.

I have tried with below code but I was not able to read the cmd prompt display/output in java.

```
File file = new File("D://Projects/quantum");
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"ping localhost\"", null, file);

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [this out](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8)

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir"); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very fragile implementation of running a `Process`.

### General tips.

- Read and implement ***all*** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).
- Once that is done, ignore the fact the article explicitly refers to the `Runtime.exec()` method and establish the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`, which makes it easier to implement some of the recommendations of the first linked article.
- But even then, break the `String` command into a `String[]` arguments of command.